# Laptop freezes, crashes, and then reboots after suspension

Tags: suspend, laptop, hp, freeze, crash

My laptop: HP 255 G8; AMD Ryzen 7 5700U; 8GB RAM; Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.19.0-051900-generic.

Everything is normal if I work with it without suspending, but if I suspend and then resume, it will often crash some time later. It first freezes (if I listen to music it repeats for several seconds with fans blasting on full speed), then reboots by itself. After rebooting, everything goes back to normal, though it still sometimes crashes like that after several hours of normal work. If I reboot manually after a crash, it doesn't seem to crash by itself.

- [some logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWfoa.png)
- [more logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM1dg.jpg)

Please explain what I need to add if this is not enough information; I am new to Ubuntu and to Linux in general.

Comment: How much SWAP space do you have?

Comment: 2 GB of SWAP space.

Comment: Increased to 10 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't resolve random crashes after suspend, so I just made my laptop to just turn off the screen when lid is closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread in HP forum but without solution.
[HP community](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-Notebooks/HP-255-G8-restarts-after-it-was-set-to-sleep/td-p/8323811)

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 with Kernel 5.19. Until now no reboots after suspend.

You can try to upgrade to 22.04. To easy upgrade to newest kernel, you can install "Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer".

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install mainline -y
```

Start: Activities > Show Applications > Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer

Source: [How to install Linux mainline kernel](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-linux-mainline-kernel-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/)

Comment: how will this help solve the problem?

Comment: After updating both kernel and ubuntu version it's now works for mush longer, but still crashes.